# Additional page types in Sulu

Tags: symfony4, sulu

I'm using Symfony 4 with Sulu. I understand that by default I can set page types of content, internal link and external link - is there a way to add additional custom types to this list? My use case is that I want to differentiate between internal links to separate Sulu pages, and internal links to locations within the react router on our single page app.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but currently there is no way to extend the page types, and the are tightly coupled within the system, so changing that would not be very easy.